# Azure Functions OpenApi extensions multiple File Uploads POST request

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, swagger-ui

[Single File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70740176/23111310)

Using the above solution I'm able to upload single file but how to upload multiple files.

[This is how I'm able upload single file using below request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQYS2.png)
request body for Single file upload:

```
    public class UploadRequest
    {
        public byte[] FormFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

But I want to upload multiple files. I tried using List<byte[]> but it is not working like that

```
 public class UploadRequest
 {
     public List<byte[]> FormFiles { get; set; }
 }
```

[multiple files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fYWN.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include a byte count for each file so the files can be separated when they are received.  The normal method is using one byte[].  Then add byte count and data for each file 1) Byte Count file one 2) File one 3) Byte Count  file two 4) File two 5) Byte Count file three 6) file three.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Functions OpenApi extensions multiple File Uploads POST request

You can use below code to upload multiple files using post request and I followed [Document](https://devkimchi.com/2021/10/27/transmitting-binary-data-via-openapi-on-azure-functions/) :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp103
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
        [OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "multipart/form-data", bodyType: typeof(RithwikData), Required = true, Description = "Image data")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "image/png", bodyType: typeof(FileContentResult), Summary = "Image data", Description = "This returns the image", Deprecated = false)]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "POST", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var rith_input_files = req.Form.Files;
            var rith_images = new List<byte[]>();

            foreach (var iter in rith_input_files)
            {
                using (var rms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await iter.CopyToAsync(rms).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    rith_images.Add(rms.ToArray());
                }
            }

            var rith_data = rith_images.Count > 0 ? rith_images[0] : new byte[0]; 
            var rith_response = new FileContentResult(rith_data, "image/png");

            return rith_response;
        }
    }

    internal class RithwikData
    {
        public List<IFormFile> InputFiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: @RitwikBojja, Its working from postman but I am expecting from swagger page.

Comment: @RitwikBojja, could you provide an update on this? If there is any progress, please share the solution as I require it urgently. Thank you.

Comment: Trying it @Phani will provide an update if i get